# Android using one Method for multiple Views

Tags: java, android, methods

For example I have multiple chronometers in my app. I currently copy and paste the same method and change the views within the code for all 3. Is there a way to use one method for chronographs and just pass a view in as an argument?

This is my current code.

How would I add a view parameter?

> public void startClickterm1 (View view){
>
> ```
> if(chronorunt1 == false){
>     chronot1.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
>     chronot1.start();
>     chronorunt1 = true;
>     Vibrator vib = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
>     vib.vibrate(100);}
>
>
> else
>
> {
>
>
>
>         }}
> ```
>
> public void stopClickterm1 (View view){
>
> ```
>         chronot1.stop();    // stop chronometer here
>         chronot1.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
>         chronorunt1 = false;
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Without seeing any code, it's difficult to advise you based purely on just a description. Post some code.

Comment: Are [fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You have just said it: add a parameter of type `View` to the method.